# Getting mad with Microsoft Oauth 2.0 Azure Apps ... can't understand tenants and microsoft account types

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm trying to add Oauth2.0 to my app ... (through Socialite library of Laravel, but the framework or language is not the problem).

I've signed to Microsoft with a normal account (name@mycompany.com), I don't have 365 or any subscription to Microsoft, it's a standard account used to, also, some Azure services.

I've created the app, as said here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

It's working as a charm ... but just with personal Microsoft accounts. So, any "professional" or "company" account in Microsoft can't login.

I read about that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/error-code-aadsts50020-user-account-identity-provider-does-not-exist

And I have the manifest.json correctly ... I have the

```
    "signInAudience": "AzureADandPersonalMicrosoftAccount",
```

But i wonder if I need to register in the Microsoft Partner Program, in order to get the "blue ticker" as a authenticated company.

The problem is about tenants, azure's directory and all stuff, but sincerely, it's a mess and I don't know what to do.

What kind of accounts can create an app to allow users (ANY user with ANY microsoft account) to login in your app with oAuth 2.0 ?

Is it necessary to be a Microsoft Partner ?

Is it necessary to create the app with an account having a paid subscription ?

Thank you !

Comment: You don't need to be a partner. But if you want any account to be able to sign in without adding them to your Azure Active Directory, you need to look at Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Or when setting up the app, make sure you select: "Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts".

Comment: But this is one of the toughest things to setup correctly in the Microsoft space.

Comment: @jessehouwing I already have "Accounts in any organizational directory and personal Microsoft accounts" ... If I look for Azure AD B2C ... will BOTH (professional and personal) accounts be able to login ?

Answer (score 1):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results as below:***

I created an **Azure AD Multitenant Application** (*Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts*):

[image]

The **manifest** of my Azure AD Application looks as below:

[image]

- For Azure AD Single Tenant Application, the authorize URL or sign-in URL must be **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID`**.
- For Azure AD Multitenant Application (*Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts*), the authorize URL or sign-in URL must be **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common`**.
- For Accounts in any organizational directory (*Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant*), the authorize URL or sign-in URL must be **`https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations`**.

I tried to **authorize** the users using below endpoint:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

When I tried to login with personal account, I got the **error** as below:

[image]

**To resolve the error, make use of **`common`** endpoint as below:**

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
&client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

***I am able to login with the personal account successfully as below:***

[image]

[image]

> Is it necessary to be a Microsoft Partner? Is it necessary to create
> the app with an account having a paid subscription?

There is no need of paid subscription or to be a Microsoft Partner to create an Azure AD Application and authenticate users with OAuth 2.0.

***If still the issue persists, try the below:***

- Try to sign out from active session and sign in again from different browser or private browser session.
- Try to clear the cookies and cache and sign-in.
- Refer this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-client-application-configuration#authority) and check the authority of the Azure AD Application and try.

Comment: Thank you for the big response !!! I already had the supported account types as mentioned and I used the "common" endpoint (I also tried my tenant as endpoint) ,  and the problem persist yet. I'm trying always in a "private browser" ... all things shown are already tried, and problem persist :-( I've even created from scratch everything ... microsoft professional accounts can't login :(

Comment: Could you confirm the endpoint you are using to authorize users?

Comment: Yes, I've tried "common" and  my tenant endpoint

Comment: Microsoft professional accounts in the sense you are refferring to personal accounts?

Comment: I refer to personal accounts (live.com, hotmail.com, xbox ...), and professional accounts (people that receive microsoft/teams accouns from their companies, with its own domain name)... these ones are failing ... any microsoft account with own domain name